# Laravel homestead connect to local elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, homestead

I have a project running in the latest Laravel Homestead environment.
I would like to make use of Elasticsearch which is running on my local computer where Homestead is installed.

It seems that I can't connect from the Homestead to the Elasticsearch (localhost:9200) because homestead will search on it's own 9200 port.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using localhost:9200 use your computer ip in homestead project.

Search your local pc ip,

if window : `ipconfig /all`

mac or linux : `ifconfig`

You will find : `inet 192.168.1.151`

Then use example : `192.168.1.151:9200` as elasticsearch port in your homestead or if `localhost:9200` not working then try : `127.0.0.1` also

Answer (score 0):

You can configure port forwarding from homestead to your local machine   by adding this line to Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 62000
```

After

```
vagrant reload
```

you will be able to connect to your elasticsearch instance with:

> localhost:62000